# .net generating onclick

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, sharepoint, web-parts

I am doing a form POST that looks like

```
<form action="http://ServerName/fse5/main/FormPost.aspx" id="frmLogin" method="post" target="_blank">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
    <%= CompleteRequest %>
    <input type="submit" name="__exclude__Submit" value="Run Illustration Software Online" runat="server" />
</table>    
</form>
```

However, when I render this HTML the input tag looks like

```
<input onclick="if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') Page_ClientValidate(''); " name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$IllustrationSoftwareComponent$ctl00" type="submit" value="Run Illustration Software Online" />
```

How come ASP.net is adding onClick and name attribute? How do I stop this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop it, don't make it a user control by adding runat="server"; it seems that you don't want it/need it.